# bashのheadやtailで省略された行数を一緒に表示する

Tags: bash

`head`や`tail`コマンドでファイルの一部を表示したとき、「表示されなかった行が何行あるか」を一緒に表示できないでしょうか。

`file.txt`が以下の内容としたとき

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

このように表示されると嬉しいです

```
$ head -n 3 file.txt

aaa
bbb
ccc
(2lines omitted)
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 対象がファイル**でない**場合（まあ要するにキャラクタデバイス）にも `tail` や `head` は対応しているので一筋縄ではいかないです。常に絶対にファイルしか扱わないってことならすでに回答がある感じ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awkを使うのはいかがでしょうか？

```
awk -v N=3 'NR <= N{print} END {if(NR-N>0)printf("(%dlines omitted)\n",
NR-N)}' file.txt
```

指定行数Nに達するまで`NR <= N{print}`内容を表示し、最後に残り行数を表示します。

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.8

$ cat file.txt | { sed -u '3q'; printf '(%d lines omitted)\n' $(wc -l); }
aaa
bbb
ccc
(2 lines omitted)

$ seq 100 | { sed -u '3q'; printf '(%d lines omitted)\n' $(wc -l); }
1
2
3
(97 lines omitted)
```

Answer (score 0):

複雑なことをやれば既に回答されているように**一緒に表示**することはできますが、分けて扱えばもっと簡単に済ませられます。

`wc`コマンドを使えばファイルの行数を表示してくれます。

```
$ wc -l file.txt
5 file.txt
$ wc -l < file.txt
5
```